# Visual Studio possible bug for weird bracket behavior

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

I am writing some C# code with visual studio and I have a weird behavior with brackets. Let's see an example.

First I write this code:

[image]

Then when I add a single bracket with <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> I get this:

[image]

The entire class gets selected. How can I avoid this? The issue came out after the update to the latest version.

---

I am using the latest version of everything. I have VS 15.8.0, C# 7.3 and the .NET 4.7.2, any idea?

Please note that some times, after a `{` the entire class gets selected and I am not able to type the closed bracket `}`.

**This happens when I write C++ as well.** (like a new Console App). I have tested it right now in an empty project and the issue is here on C++ as well (VS 15.8.0, C++17). I have added a random c++ function to a library of mine and I have this behavior like in C#!

---

**Possible solution**

When I get the entire text selected, I press <kbd>esc</kbd> and the text gets deselected (plus the cursor is still at the right place). This is annoying AND this wasn't a problem 2 hours ago (when I had the old version).

Comment: Nothing of vital importance, but this is annoying because I had no problems with the previous version! Should I disable somehow the autocomplete for brackets?

Comment: Sounds like a bug that could get in because of somebody's assumption that the key combination is unused (as it would be on a U.S. keyboard). Perhaps some function got bound to a shortcut in the update?

Comment: @molbdnilo Disabling brackets autocompletion doesnt work. It may be an issue with European keyboards... How do you type the { in your keyboard?

Comment: I've updated my VS right now to test this and I can't reproduce this bug. I have a PT keyboard and I use Alt Gr + 7 to '{'..

Comment: @Raffaele on british and american keyboards `{` is obtained by pressing `Shift + [`

Comment: I have the italian layout and with AltGr + Shift + [ it is broken. It may be an issue with this...

Comment: I will test this soon with an Italian keyboard

Comment: Sounds like something to tell MS about using Help->Submit feedback in VS.

Comment: That sure sounds like a bug in Visual Studio, but I don't see why it is on topic for this site. You haven't asked a question in this question; you've just reported a bug to a bunch of people who have no ability to fix the bug. **Report the bug to Microsoft please**.

Comment: This is a [bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/296638/keyboard-binding-for-italian-layout.html) in keyboard binding for Italian layout and [has been fixed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#15.8.2) in Visual Studio 2017 15.8.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an Italian keyboard and I can reproduce this behavior after the update. The fact is:

- <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>{</kbd> adds an open bracket as expected
- <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>}</kbd> selects the entire declaration of the class/struct in which you are creating the method

I wasn't able to find the keyword map that generates this behaviour (under `Tools > Environment > Keyboard`).

A solution may be the following: be sure that you have the automatic bracket completion enabled (which is already, by default) and type only the open bracket. In this way, when you type `{` you automatically get the closed bracket.

What if you need to type a `}` then? Well, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>125</kbd> and you'll get the close bracket (open bracket is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>123</kbd>.

Comment: I have had the same idea because it seems to be the only good thing to do. I'll enable the completion and type only the {